# Select record between a starting date and a specific number of days after this starting date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

```
CREATE TABLE MeteoForecast (
  id                   BigInt(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  localization_id      BigInt(20) NOT NULL,
  seasonal_forecast_id BigInt(20),
  meteo_warning_id     BigInt(20),
  start_date           DateTime NOT NULL,
  end_date             DateTime NOT NULL,
  min_temp             Float,
  max_temp             Float,
  icon_link            VarChar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

It contains some data like these:

```
id                   localization_id      start_date              end_date                min_temp             max_temp             icon_link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    1                    18/09/2017 06:00:00     18/09/2017 12:00:00     15                   24                   Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2                    1                    18/09/2017 12:00:00     18/09/2017 18:00:00     15                   24                   Light_Rain.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
3                    1                    19/09/2017 06:00:00     19/09/2017 12:00:00     12                   22                   Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
4                    1                    19/09/2017 12:00:00     19/09/2017 18:00:00     13                   16                   Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
5                    1                    20/09/2017 06:00:00     20/09/2017 12:00:00     18                   26                   Light_Rain.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
6                    1                    20/09/2017 12:00:00     20/09/2017 18:00:00     17                   25                   Light_Rain.png
```

So, as you can see in the previous dataset, each record have a starting datetime and and ending datetime. This because I am collecting more forecast information in a specific day (it is based on time range, in the example for each day a record from 06:00 am to 12:00 and another record from 12:00 to 18:00 pm).

As you can see I created this query that extract information into a specific range of **DateTime**, this is the code of my query:

```
SELECT
*  
FROM MeteoForecast as MF
WHERE
      MF.start_date between  '2017-09-18 06:00:00' and '2017-09-20 12:00:00'
```

It works fine but I need to change this clause in the following way:

- In the **between** operator want to specify only the starting date (possibly without having to specify also the time).
- Instead the *end date** of the between operator I want to use a number of days.

So basically I want to pass to the query the starting date and a number representing the number of days after this starting day.

How can I change my query to implement this behavior?

Comment: Please narrow the question to the problem, not unnecessary foreign keys or a huge query whereas you're only interested in one part of the where clause. Edited it for you to give an example. It can be shortened much more, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) in `BETWEEN` like this:

```
WHERE MF.start_date between '2017-09-18 06:00:00'
                        AND DATE_ADD('2017-09-18 06:00:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

So in this case, you just need two paramters the `start date` and the days interval to pass to the query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the date_add function (in MySQL, which is your sql platform):

```
    SELECT
MF.start_date, 
MF.min_temp, 
MF.max_temp, 
MF.icon_link,
MFD.id,
MFD.meteo_forecast_description_name,
MFD.description
FROM MeteoForecast as MF
INNER JOIN MeteoForecast_MeteoForecastDescription as MF_MFD
      ON MF.id = MF_MFD.meteo_forecast_id 
INNER JOIN MeteoForecastDescription as MFD
      ON MF_MFD.meteo_forecast_description_id = MFD.id     
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
      ON MFD.language_id = LNG.id
WHERE
      MF.start_date between  '2017-09-18 06:00:00' and DATE_ADD(MF.start_date, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
      AND LNG.id = 1
```

- I used 4 as an example, change it to whatever you want.
- You can read more about date_add function here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp